# Redirect and Response on submit Laravel 4

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, response

I need a file to download when a form is submitted, however I also want to have the page redirect back to the form with a "form submitted" message.

Obviously something like this wont work:

```
    return Redirect::to('form')->with('sent', true);
    $downloadLink = base_path().'/something.pdf';
    return Response::download($downloadLink);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to post the form data via ajax and on the response (inside a json object) you can return the file url you want and redirect to that file if everything was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = array('sent' => true, 'downloadlink' => $downloadlink);
return Redirect::to('form')->with('data', $data);
```

if JSON:

```
return Response::json(['sent' => true, 'data' => $data']);
```

to access data in view:

```
var_dump($data['sent']), var_dump($data['downloadlink'])
```